# Remove function for tree c++

Tags: c++, arrays, tree

So i need a function that only removes the last node of the tree. Everything im finding online says to use a vector instead of an array, but my assignment says to use an array. So im thinking of using two arrays just not sure how to implement it. Help please this is what i have as my code so far, all i think i need is the remove function. Thanks in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
template <class item>
class Tree {
public:
  // typedef int value_type;
   typedef std::size_t size_type;
   static const size_type CAPACITY = 30;
   Tree() { used = 0; }
   void leftchild(int index)
   {
       if((2*index)+1 > used)
       {
            cout <<"No child" << endl;
       }
       else
       cout << "\nLeft Child of Index " << index << ": " << data[(2*index)+1] << endl;
   }
   void rightchild (int index)
   {
       if((2*index)+2 >= used)
       {
           cout <<"No child" << endl;
       }
       else
       cout << "\nRight Child of Index " << index << data[(2*index)+2] << endl;
   }
   void parent (int index)
   {
      if(((index-1)/2) < 0)
      {
          cout << "No Parent" << endl;
      }
      else
      cout << "\nParent: " << data[(index-1)/2] <<endl;
   }
   void insert(item entry)
   {
       data[used] = entry;
       ++used;
   }
   void remove()
   {

   }
   void display()
   {
       for(int i = 0; i < used; i++)
        {
            cout << data[i];
        }
    }


private:
    item data[CAPACITY];
    size_type used;
};

 int main()
 {
Tree<char> test;
test.insert('A'); //Index [0]
test.insert('L'); //Index [1]
test.insert('G'); //Index [2]
test.insert('O'); //Index [3]
test.insert('R'); //Index [4]
test.insert('I'); //Index [5]
test.insert('T'); //Index [6]
test.insert('H'); //Index [7]
test.insert('M'); //Index [8]
test.insert('S'); //Index [9]
test.display();
//test.remove();
test.display();
test.leftchild(4);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if you want to remove some node other than the last?

Comment: I dont know about that it just says to write a function that removes only the last node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply decrease used by 1:

```
void remove()
{
    if (used > 0) 
        used--;
}
```

Also fix your leftChild():

```
if((2*index)+1 >= used)
```

Comment: Hmmm but when i do this and call left child at index 4 it still shows the 's' is there, is there no way around this?

Comment: That's because the check in leftChild() uses '>' where it should use '>='. Off-by-one errors are the nicest.

Comment: Yep, you used `>=` correctly in the right child, but `>` in left child.